# pass FORTRAN READ arguments into a string

Tags: fortran

I have a string including the names of the variables I want read, and I would like to pass this string to the read function. This could allow me to change the name of the variables I read just changing the vector with the names of the variables.
An  example could be:

```
PROGRAM test
implicit none

  integer :: no, age
  character(len=20) :: myname, vars

vars='no, myname, age'
read(*, '(i4,a20,i4)') vars
print*, no, myname, age 

END PROGRAM test
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into "NAMELIST" I/O, which maybe does what you're after. Often, namelist IO has various issues, and people often resort to writing their own custom IO routines anyway. But if it's enough for what you want, it's quite easy to use. E.g.

```
program nmltest
  implicit none
  real :: x
  integer :: y
  namelist /mynml/ x, y
  x = 4711
  y = 42
  write(*, mynml)
end program nmltest
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @janneb. Could I do that reading data from a space-delimiter file?

Comment: @ManuelRamón: No, namelist input must be in namelist format. See the output of my test program for an example of the syntax. If you need to parse some other syntax, you need to roll your own parsing routines (or find code to do it somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Fortran is a compiled language. It would be hard (to impossible) for the `READ` statement to extract variable addresses from the string list at run-time. That's why, as noted by janneb, Fortran provides the `NAMELIST` operator which became part of the language standard since Fortran 90 (some Fortran 77 also had support for namelists but it was non-standard and no compatibility was guaranteed between compilers). It is used like that:

```
...
NAMELIST /vars/ no, age, myname
...
READ(*, NML=vars)
...
```

The input should be something like this:

```
! Input can contain comments starting with exclamation marks

! And blank lines too
&vars
 no = 12,
 myname = 'sometext'/
```

Formatted input/output is not possible with `NAMELIST` though.

Comment: Thanks @Hristo. If I understand the NAMELIST statement, the input file must have a specific format. Is there some way to do my job to read a space-delimiter file?

Comment: You can write your own input parser but that would be tedious and not flexible.

Comment: +1. No idea why this was not upvoted yet. By the way as one of the top users of the FORTRAN tag, I thought you'd be delighted to see this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6252/5 on a brand new SE site!