# Input file for a Fortran program, containing "&PROBIN"

Tags: file, input, fortran

I have the following code (it's an input file for a Fortran code from some link):

```
&PROBIN 
model_file = "model_file" 
drdxfac = 5 
max_levs = 1 
n_cellx = 106 
n_celly = 106 
n_cellz = 106 
max_grid_size = 32 
anelastic_cutoff = 1.e3 
base_cutoff_density = 1.e3 
sponge_center_density = 3.d6 
sponge_start_factor = 3.333d0 
sponge_kappa = 10.0d0 
max_mg_bottom_nlevels = 3 
mg_bottom_solver = 4 
hg_bottom_solver = 4 
spherical_in = 1 
dm_in = 3 
do_sponge = .true. 
prob_hi_x = 2.e10 
prob_hi_y = 2.e10 
prob_hi_z = 2.e10 
max_step  = 100 
init_iter = 1 
stop_time = 30000. 
plot_int  = 10 
plot_deltat = 10.0d0 
chk_int   = 100 
cflfac = 0.7d0 
init_shrink = 0.1d0 
max_dt_growth = 1.1d0 
use_soundspeed_firstdt = T 
use_divu_firstdt = T 
bcx_lo = 12 
bcx_hi = 12 
bcy_lo = 12 
bcy_hi = 12 
bcz_lo = 12 
bcz_hi = 12 
verbose = 1 
mg_verbose = 1 
cg_verbose = 1 
do_initial_projection = T 
init_divu_iter = 3 
drive_initial_convection = T 
stop_initial_convection = 20 
do_burning = F 
velpert_amplitude = 1.d6 
velpert_radius = 2.d7 
velpert_scale = 1.d7 
velpert_steep = 1.d5 
enthalpy_pred_type = 1 
evolve_base_state = F 
dpdt_factor = 0.0d0 
use_tfromp = T 
single_prec_plotfiles = T 
use_eos_coulomb = T 
plot_trac = F 
/
```

My question is: what is `&PROBIN`?  where can I find more information on it?

Comment: Please reformat your question, not with a bullet list but as code (the {} in the edit bar of the question). The `&PROBIN` is probably an string read by the program, so look in the Fortran code you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Such an input file would be typically read using *namelist formatting*.

Details can be found using this term.  One example of use is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896891/3157076) to a question about input.

In summary, the `&PROBIN` says that following (up to a terminating `/`) is a set of pairs for variables and values.  These correspond to the namelist `probin`.  In the source file we would find a `namelist` statement:

```
namelist /probin/ list, of, variables
```

with corresponding input statement

```
read(unit, NML=probin)
```

where the unit `unit` is connected to that input file.

---

Of course, it's entirely possible that the file is an input file processed in the "usual" way.  In this case `&PROBIN` has no special significance.  The `&PROBIN` is necessary to support namelist formatting, but not unique to it.